# Laravel : How to Pass Other Parameter on Crinsane Shopping Cart

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-5.8

I have to pas the `purchase_prices` field from the `product` table to the crinsane shopping cart so that I can see the `profit` from each transaction and save it to the database.

Here's my code on **CartController**

```php
$product = Product::find($id);

Cart::add([
    'id' => $product->id,
    'name' => $product->name,
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => $product->sell_price,
    'options' => ['purchase' => $product->purchase_price]
]);

return back();
```

but the purchase is not stored

```
Collection {#257 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df" => CartItem {#258 ▼
      +rowId: "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df"
      +id: 2
      +qty: 1
      +name: "Beras B"
      +price: 12000.0
      +weight: 1.0
      +options: CartItemOptions {#259 ▼
        #items: []
      }
      -associatedModel: null
      -taxRate: 0
      -discountRate: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: does Cart::add accept arrays as values>?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem)
    <?php $no++ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$no}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartItem->qty}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartItem->options->purchase}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update</a>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I see you are trying to retrieve multiple row from table when you write

> {{$cartItem->options->purchase}}

you should can that to the specific row name you want to display and it should match the name used in your table.

Comment: how i call the purchase field in option ?

Comment: just change this {{$cartItem->options->purchase}} to this {{$cartItem->purchase}}